# ASP.net or PHP webmail app I can install on my shared hosting domain with inteface similar to Gmail

Tags: php, asp.net, webmail

I'm looking for either an **ASP.net** or **PHP** based **webmail app** I can install on my **shared hosting**.

I want to set this up on one of my domains for my **Gmail** address, due to Gmail being blocked at work.

I'd like the interface to be as similar to Gmail as possible, conversation view, labels, starred emails etc if possible well at least allow me to keep with my GTD workflow.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't get why this is on SO. Shouldn't it be on SuperUser/ServerFault?

Answer (score 7):

The closest one I know of is [Roundcube](https://roundcube.net/), but I'd be glad to find anything closer! Roundcube is written in PHP. The only thing about Roundcube which reminds me of Gmail is the simplicity and AJax drag-and-drop.

From their website:

> [image: Screen Capture]
>   <sub>(source: [roundcube.net](https://roundcube.net/images/homescreen.jpg))</sub>
>
> Roundcube webmail...
>
> ...is a
>   browser-based multilingual IMAP client
>   with an application-like user
>   interface. It provides full
>   functionality you expect from an
>   e-mail client, including MIME support,
>   address book, folder manipulation,
>   message searching and spell checking

Comment: I don't know of any, but I'm a PHP guy, not an ASP guy. Hopefully someone else will provide an answer for you!

Comment: Is there a away to set these up on my own domain for a gmail account such that if I use this interface to send email, my sent emails are sync'd across to the gmail servers sent items and my Gmail still represents the complete state of what has happened with my account?

Comment: @m3ntat I'm not sure. I think that if you set up Roundcube to access gMail over IMAP, it should do what you're asking for but I've never tried it myself. YMMV!

Answer (score 1):

For .Net you might try http://mail.afterlogic.com. There is a list of mostly php applications at http://www.noupe.com/ajax/10-ajax-webmail-clients.html. Though nothing close to the interface you get with gmail.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just webmail interfaces (using AJAX) you're looking for, then here are some candidates (RoundCube was already mentioned) :

- http://roundcube.net/
- http://atmail.org/
- http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee/webmail-lite.asp
- http://www.horde.org/dimp/

Comment: I just removed Zimbra because you want to install it on shared hosting and AFAIK Zimbra is a complete groupware solution :p.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend AfterLogic's **WebMail Lite** (although it's not free, has versions in both PHP and ASP.NET). You can try out a live demo (ASP.NET version) [here](http://www.afterlogic.com/webmail-lite/webmail.aspx).

Taken from their site, here are some features:

> *Screenshot*
>
> [image: Screenhot]
>   <sub>(source: [afterlogic.com](http://www.afterlogic.com/img/screen-wml.png))</sub>

>
>

> Functionality
>
> - Multiple domains
> - Mail folders and nested folders
> - Address Book (Contacts and Groups)
> - Mail filters
> - Mail Search
> - IMAP synchronization
> - IMAP quotas
> - IMAP search
> - Managing IMAP folders
> - Delivery confirmation
> - Auto-responder (vacation message)
>
> Compatibility
>
> - Supports SMTP/IMAP/POP3/XMail protocols
> - MySQL, MS SQL or MS Access database backend
> - Supports AJAX in all modern browsers: IE6+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera
> - Static HMTL option if AJAX not available
> - International charsets, including UTF-8
> - Accurate e-mail parser and viewer
>
> Usability
>
> - Message preview pane
> - Auto-complete of e-mail addresses
> - Keyboard shortcuts
> - Spell-check
> - Compose e-mails in HTML (WYSIWYG) or plain-text modes
> - Right-to-left (RTL) rendering for Arabic and Hebrew
> - Built-in and user-defined skins
> - Personal user settings
>     Web administration panel (manage system settings and domains)
>
> Security
>
> - Supports SSL connections with mail servers
> - Can block javascript and external images in e-mails
> - Spam filter with self-learning
> - Anti-virus integration
>
> Deployment
>
> - cPanel integration ([how](https://web.archive.org/web/20091013154658/http://www.afterlogic.com:80/products/webmail-lite-php-docs/index-cpanel-integration.htm))
> - Web-based installation wizard
> - Basic integration (bypass login screen)
> - Source code provided (modification allowed)

Comment: I'm wondering how is that going to work with Gmail labels, I use labels extensively as part of my GTD process...

Answer (score 0):

Consider using SSH to proxy HTTP. Or, you can try a [proxy written in PHP](http://www.phproxy.org/)... or simply use [someone else's proxy](http://vtunnel.com/) somewhere. Have you tried using Google's Translate feature to access to Gmail (use Google as a proxy to Google)? Sometimes this is enough to break basic web filtering.

The advantage to a proxy is keeping the GMail interface completely intact.